# Query all posts where meta value is empty

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, meta-query

I want to query posts where meta value is empty. for example, I want to get these three posts, with no meta values:
[image]

Already tried:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_alt',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$attachments = new WP_Query($args);
```

and:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_alt',
            'value' => null,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

But it doesn't work..

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot about the *inherit* post status. The default one in `WP_Query` is *publish*.

You should also use `=` instead of `LIKE`, to avoid using `LIKE '%%'` in the SQL query.

So try to add this:

```
'post_status' => 'inherit'
```

and

```
'compare' => '='
```

into your query arguments, to match the empty `_wp_attachment_image_alt` string values.

Comment: Yep I forget the post_status, and also now it works with '='. Whats the difference between '=' and 'LIKE'? I though '=' is for ints and 'LIKE' is for strings..Thanks

Comment: If you use `LIKE` in the meta query of `WP_Query` for e.g. the value `'test'`, then the generated SQL query will contain `LIKE '%test%'` where `%` is a wildcard. So in your case it was `LIKE '%%'`, that gives all values. Note that the meta value column is of type `longtext` so any numbers there are stored as strings. @Avishay

Answer (score -1):

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_alt',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // this should work...
    ),
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, since the key is exists..